# dynamically add div container in angular 6

Tags: html, css, angular, angular6

**How to dynamically add div containers in angular?.**

Please look at my html code. Whenever I will click "Add" button, one new div should add left side of that button. Dynamically it should add multiple containers based on how any clicks. Everything should add in horizontal wise. If it is more containers by default it should add scroll and it be in uniform. Can anyone please help me to do this in `angular 6.`

```css
#content{
    width:100%;
    height:90px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
#contentInside{
    width:100px;
    height:70px;
    margin:7px;
    border:1px solid black;
    display:inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <div id="contentInside">
    
    </div>
    <button (click)="add()">Add</button> 

</div>
```

I am new in angular. Please anyone help me to do this.

Comment: So, you want multiple `contentInside` `div`s when user clicks on `Add` button?

Comment: yes. If i click one time it should add one container, like this how many times i will click, that much containers should add in horizontal wise

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is with an array. Let me show you how.

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-47yztq?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

I create an array of empty elements, and call it `containers`.

Every time, user clicks on `Add` button, I push another element to this array.
The element I push does not matter, so I push the current length of the array so it will end up like `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4...]`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-comp',
  template: `
    <div id="content">
      <div id="contentInside" *ngFor="let container of containers"></div>
      <button (click)="add()">Add</button>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [`
    #content{
      width:100%;
      height:90px;
      border:1px solid black;
    }
    #contentInside{
      width:100px;
      height:70px;
      margin:7px;
      border:1px solid black;
      display:inline-flex;
    }
  `]
})

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  containers = [];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  add() {
    this.containers.push(this.containers.length);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try Using this example with updated css for autoscroll:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pujraw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css