# Angular: Add/Remove elements from DOM

Tags: angular

To work around a [problem with dragula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56108033/disable-dont-offer-some-drop-locations-on-ng2-dragula) I thought I add and remove the elements from the DOM instead. The goal is to use some placeholder elements to get the layout I want (left aligned elements in a centered container at all resolutions). These placeholder elements have to be placed at the end!

I tried the following approaches:

- [ngIf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51019457/426227): problem here is that it can happen that the *invisible* elements are not placed at the end. Through drag & drop it can happen that the dropped element is on the last place and the *invisible* elements are between.
- [push elements on the array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50925371/426227): here I tried to add the class *invisible* with the help of the *ngClass* directive, but it didn't update it correctly, when I set my boolean variable while pushing items on the array. The class was never applied.
- [`ElementRef`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52017679/426227): removing an element from the DOM worked, but I didn't figured out how to add one
- [`Renderer2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52017539/426227): my current approach, where `removeChild()` only removes one child despite it is called a second time

Template:

```html
<div #button_area class="button_area" dragula="cards" [dragulaModel]="cards" (dragulaModelChange)="cards = $event">
  <div *ngFor="let c of cards" id="{{ 'card-' + c.id }}" [ngClass]="calculateClasses(c)" [ngStyle]="calculateStyles(c)" (click)="onSelect($event, c)">
    <!-- some irrelevant html code -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Typescript:

```ts
@ViewChild('button_area') private buttonAreaElement: ElementRef;

constructor(public dragulaService: DragulaService,
          private renderer: Renderer2) {
    // something irrelevant
}

addPlaceholderElements() {
    const placeholder = this.buttonAreaElement.nativeElement.querySelector('.invisible');

    if (placeholder === null) {
        const placeholder1 = this.renderer.createElement('div');
        this.renderer.addClass(placeholder1, 'card');
        this.renderer.addClass(placeholder1, 'invisible');
        this.renderer.appendChild(this.buttonAreaElement.nativeElement, placeholder1);

        const placeholder2 = this.renderer.createElement('div');
        this.renderer.addClass(placeholder2, 'card');
        this.renderer.addClass(placeholder2, 'invisible');
        this.renderer.appendChild(this.buttonAreaElement.nativeElement, placeholder2);
    }
}

removePlaceholderElements() {
    const placeholder1 = this.buttonAreaElement.nativeElement.querySelector('.invisible');
    if (placeholder1 !== null) {
        this.renderer.removeChild(this.buttonAreaElement.nativeElement, placeholder1);
    }

    const placeholder2 = this.buttonAreaElement.nativeElement.querySelector('.invisible');
    if (placeholder2 !== null) {
        this.renderer.removeChild(this.buttonAreaElement.nativeElement, placeholder2);
    }
}
```

As you can see I use the [`querySelector()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40759622/426227) method for this. *placeholder2* is found, but not removed from the DOM. But why?

I'm using Angular v. 7.2.5.

**Edit:**

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nlw7vw) is the MVCE. There the issue with the deletion doesn't occur. Haven't figured out what the difference is ... Why doesn't `removeChild()` remove the child? Is this a timing issue?

Comment: Modifying the DOM yourself is usually a bad idea. Especially with Angular libraries such as Dragula. Please provide a [mcve] of your issue, and I'll see how I can work around your problem !

Comment: @Maryannah: I have added a stackblitz project (see edited question). Perhaps you have a better idea how to solve this.

Comment: Had an issue or two with dragula as well - why don't you use native ng-7 `CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray, transferArrayItem` from `@angular/cdk/drag-drop` instead of dragula ?

Comment: @iLuvLogix I love that suggestion. Dragula is old and way less updated than the CDK ! As for the OP, I'll look at it right now and keep you updated

Comment: OP, what's your issue exactly ? What are the steps to reproduce ?

Comment: @iLuvLogix: First of all the real underlying issue is a layout issue (because I need the placeholder elements for centering). Second, cdk has problems with multiple lines and horizontal direction in the flexbox (see [here](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/13372)). And it seems that it isn't get fixed.

Comment: @Maryannah: To get the right layout I use placeholder elements. When I use the placeholder elements these are possible locations for `dragula`. I don't want them as drop location. Because I can't exclude these placeholder elements I thought I add and remove them as necessary. In my last attempt I use `Renderer2`. In my real project `removeChild` doesn't remove the child and one (of the two) placeholder element stays. In the MVCE this isn't the case, but I don't know why.

Comment: @Maryannah: Steps to reproduce in my real project: 1. Enable dragging (click on enable) 2. Change location of an element by drag & drop 3. Disable dragging 4. Enable dragging again. Here there is the placeholder element, which shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question:

As shown in the question, there are multiple ways to add or remove elements (e.g. via `Renderer2`). In general, it is not advisable to manipulate the DOM directly as [Maryannah](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56459647/angular-add-remove-elements-from-dom#comment99510894_56459647) stated. But sometimes it is the last resort.

<sup><sub>*To get the right layout I use placeholder elements. When I use the placeholder elements these are possible locations for dragula. I don't want them as drop location. Because I can't exclude these placeholder elements I thought I add and remove them as necessary. In my last attempt I use Renderer2. In my real project removeChild doesn't remove the child and one (of the two) placeholder element stays. In the MVCE this isn't the case, but I don't know why.*</sub></sup>

What was missing for my workaround of the workaround is the complete removal of all childs with the CSS class *invisible*. This now does also work in my local development environment:

```ts
removePlaceholderElements() {
    const placeholders = this.buttonAreaElement.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.invisible');
    for (var i = 0; i < placeholders.length; i++) {
        this.renderer.removeChild(this.buttonAreaElement.nativeElement, placeholders[i]);
    }
}
```